# Interact two ways with a button in Ionic 3

Tags: android, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am making an app in the Ionic 3 framework. It's a basic calculation app. I have made two inputs fields and a button. When the user press button the two variables will calculate. This is my code in HTML.

```
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
          <ion-col> 
             <ion-list>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating>Ray (r)</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="ray"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>        
            </ion-list>
            <ion-list>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating>Time (T)</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="circulationtime"> 
                </ion-input>
              </ion-item>        
            </ion-list>
          </ion-col>         
      </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
    <button ion-button full (click)="calculateTwo(ray, circulationtime)">Calculate</button>
```

And this is my code in typescript:

```
calculateTwo(ray, circulationtime){
   this.result = "Speed: " + (2 * Math.PI * ray / circulationtime) + " m/s";    
  }
```

I want the user have two ways to interact with the button:

1: he clicks on the button (works) 
2: he clicks enter on his mobile keyboard (the problem)

I already check on Google and there is a event called **(keyup.enter)** but I don't now how this event works.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the `(ngSubmit)` in combination with the `<form>` tag example:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="calculateTwo(weight, speed)">
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label floating>Massa (m)</ion-label>
          <ion-input name="weight" type="number" [(ngModel)]="weight"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label floating>Snelheid (v)</ion-label>
          <ion-input name="speed" type="number" [(ngModel)]="speed"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
<button ion-button full type="submit">Bereken</button>
```

This works fine

Answer (score 1):

you will want to use a `@HostListener` to handle key presses. this is how I use my host listeners

```
  import {HostListener} from '@angular/core'

  @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
  handleKeyPress(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.key === 'enter') {
      this.result = "Speed: " + (2 * Math.PI * this.ray / this.circulationtime) + " m/s";   
    }
  }
```

Or, you could reuse the function you already have and do this

```
  @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
  handleKeyPress(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.key === 'enter') {
      this.calculateTwo(this.ray, this.circulationtime);   
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your time I get a error at @HostListener 'Cannot find name'

Comment: Import `HostListener`

Comment: i added the import to the ts

Comment: I tested this feature on my phone but it didn't work. I have a Sony Z2 Experia.